# Gradiant background

Tags: java, android

What is the best way to make a screen like this?

[image]
I tried using GradientDrawable but without success.

Comment: you need that straps ?

Comment: Yes, I need! @Prashant

Comment: easiest? manually overriding `onDraw` and using `Paint` on `Canvas`. Check here: [Custom Drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) - last _Draw_ section. Iterate form 0 to number on needed straps and multply 1/n through height, use `canvas.drawRect`

Comment: @snachmsm I'll try

Answer (score 0):

-Try this code.It might help you :)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#010000"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="20dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#0F0F0F"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="40dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#1E1E1E"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="60dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#2D2D2D"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="80dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#3C3C3C"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="100dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#4C4C4C"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="120dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#5A5A5A"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="140dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#696969"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="160dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#787878"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="180dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#878787"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="200dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#969696"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="220dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#A5A5A5"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="240dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#B4B4B4"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="260dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#C3C3C3"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="280dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#D2D2D2"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:height="20dp" android:width="300dp" android:top="300dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#E1E1E1"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach was:

```
//Java code:

private void setGreyLevelBackground() {
    int currentColor = 0;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    LinearLayout llGreyLevel = findViewById(R.id.ll_lcd_grey_level);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(
                Color.argb(255, currentColor, currentColor, currentColor));
        llGreyLevel.addView(linearLayout);
        currentColor += 17;
    }

    llGreyLevel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_lcd_grey_level"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

</LinearLayout>
```